# Creating and image filter with python for CodeHS

Tags: python, image, imagefilter

the assignment is as follows:
"Fill in the function custom_filter that takes in an Image as a parameter, and modifies the pixels in the image in some way to create a new image, then returns that modified Image!

Make your filter unique. Experiment with different ways of modifying each pixel in the image."

and this is the code I have so far, which will not work:

```
IMAGE_URL = "https://codehs.com/uploads/c709d869e62686611c1ac849367b3245"
IMAGE_WIDTH = 420
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 300
IMAGE_LOAD_TIME = 1000

image = Image(IMAGE_URL)
image.set_size(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT)
add(image)

"""
 Filter that takes an image as a parameter
 and applies a filter, then returns the filtered image
"""
def custom_filter(image):
    custom_pixel[0] = 255 - pixel[0]
    custom_pixel[1] = 255 - pixel[1]
    custom_pixel[2] = 255 - pixel[2]
    return(custom_pixel[0], custom_pixel[1], custom_pixel[2])


def change_image():
    for x in range(image.get_width()):
        for y in range(image.get_height()):
            pixel = image.get_pixel(x,y)
            new_colors = custom_filter(image)
            image.set_red(x, y, custom_pixel[0])
            image.set_green(x, y, custom_pixel[1])
            image.set_blue(x, y, custom_pixel[2])    
    return custom_filter(image)
    

    image = custom_filter(image)
    
    
timer.set_timeout(change_image, IMAGE_LOAD_TIME)
```

Edit;
here's the error that comes up:

Traceback (most recent call last): File VFS.browser.timer.py line 13, in f msg='{0.info}\n{0.**class**.**name**}: {0.args[0]}'.format(exc) File https://static.codehs.com/gulp/7d014c9ce2d8dbe63839f802b4acce8fd580dd49/abacus/brython-graphics.html?shouldResize=false&canvasWidth=400&canvasHeight=480/__main__ line 25, in change_image for x in range(image.get_width()): UnboundLocalError: local variable 'image' referenced before assignment

I don't know what the problem with the code is, please help me, I've been trying to figure out for days and the assignment was due yesterday.

Comment: What is the error that comes up when you try to run it?

Comment: Also, what packages are you using? You should always include your usings in your question.

Comment: @AaronJones I'm not sure what a package is and how to find out which one I'm using

Comment: It looks like this is an assignment that's supposed to be run in CodeHS's IDE (https://codehs.com/) If you wanted to run this outside of that environment you would need to define some imports for packages. (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)